# Is there a definitive modern theory of semantics?

Tags: semantics

It seems like although there may be gaps in theories of phonology and syntax we have a pretty good understanding of the nature of the system. Syntax is some kind of computational system based on tree-like, nested structures and certain rules.

Is semantics by comparison still a mystery? One thing that strikes me about “meaning” is how variable it is. Metaphor indicates that concepts are like “potential clouds” with a huge variety of possible nuances depending on context.

Is there any framework attempting to map out the “meaning” of all words, as systematically as modern syntax? It should basically explicate what really happens in the brain-mind when it considers any given word, rather than being just a dictionary definition.

I don’t necessarily mean a formal language, as I’m not sure formal logic and semantics really encapsulates everything effected or contained within words.

It should be an attempt at detailing associations, as well as how human belief is influenced by utterances.

In other words, it seems like formal semantics are an attempt at reframing language as logically perfect, whereas humans are not. It would be better just to show how humans think. So a theory of meaning should be written in a theory or language of human reason and inference, a detailing of human thinking.

The only way I can think of this is that the mind builds models of reality, and one of the core aspects of that model is expectation and prediction. Maybe if there’s a single element to build the language of thought out of, it’s not generic facts, like “grass is green”, but a number of actions, like grass can be cut, grass grows.

At least this helps us focus in on the fundamental element that we need to analyse more. How does the mind “know”? Are beliefs encoded in language, i.e. thought is only possible because of language, or does language get translated into something more foundational?

Perhaps past experience and memory train a reflex - every time we have an expectation about what something is or does, we are having past temporal associations triggered.

Then, could the basis of meaning be a purely statistical association of events, with “events” as a fundamental category of the mind, sensory clusters involving vision, taste, emotions, etc?

Comment: There are things like force dynamics, which can be seen as an extension of Davidsonian formal semantics with a basis in cognitive linguistics (Talmy), and thus avoids your critique that formal semantics is focused too much on truth in the real world and not enough on our mental representations of that world. See Copley & Harley's 2015 *A force-theoretic framework for event structure* for the formalization. In that paper they also reject the notion of "event" as a primitive.

Comment: Attempts at detailing associations so far include Framenet and Wordnet, for instance. Don't forget, we know quite a bit about words, but not much at all about thoughts, so linking them up is not a simple task.